# Linux Git SSH key authorization fail

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh, ssh-keys

I made git server on digital ocean and work fine but I want to change authorization from password to SSH key.

Now it's working nice for SSH/SFTP with this server and also with my pi. But git don't want to cooperate.

I have:

- `/home/git/.ssh` on permission 700
- `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on 644

Shell for git: `/usr/bin/git-shell`

And on local machine set `.ssh/config`  to load private key from encrypted pendrive

```
isaac@Isaac-Debian:~$ ssh -vT server
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/isaac/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/isaac/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git-server1.iofist.de
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to serwer ******** port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/isaac/secret/server1git type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/isaac/secret/server1git-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LyaAW9P8EIqkyuf/lEuEIKWTTeu2/3XbOyxx8TmPXa8
debug1: Host 'server1.iofist.de' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/isaac/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/isaac/secret/server1git
Enter passphrase for key '/home/isaac/secret/server1git': 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Can you ssh from your local host to git@server? If no — the problem is not with git but with ssh. If yes — what exactly is the error? Try debugging with `GIT_TRACE=1 git $command`.

Comment: I think it's about shell but I don't want to give access this account to SSH only to Git, when was password autorotation shell work `/usr/bin/git-shell`

Comment: I added `ssh -vT` log

Comment: May you know type of shell that's work that way

Comment: **Permission denied (publickey).** — That's ssh problem, not git problem.

Answer (score 0):

> `debug1: Trying private key: /home/isaac/secret/server1git
>   Enter passphrase for key '/home/isaac/secret/server1git': 
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   Permission denied (publickey).`

At first it still wants you to have public key, so you must create it too. Second make sure you run `ssh` as a root. It will resolve the conflicts with `Permission denied (publickey)`.